# Regex error: What is wrong with this Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for a Java program which matches all JS code snippets like this:

`<script>
  window.box||((box=function(){box.q.push(arguments);}).q=[]);
  box('ns:foo','event', 'bar', {delimiter:'null',display_name:'baz',id:'12345',name:'attr_1',value:'attr_val',event_type:'abc'});
</script>`

This is what I have so far:

`private final static String SCRIPT_CODE_REG_EXP = "(^<script>\\n.*\\n  box(\\('ns:.*','event', '%s',)(\\{%s\\}){1}\\)(;\\n</script>$)";`

The JSON values {delimiter:'null',display_name:'baz',id:'12345',name:'attr_1',value:'attr_val',event_type:'abc'} will be passed in as part of String.format().

I am not able to match the JS snippet with that regex.

Comment: Do you make sure that the JSON values do not contain regex patterns (using [`Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-))?

Comment: I read about Pattern.quote(). Did you mean use that to define a pattern for calling split() method and then counting number of elements in my JSON-ish pattern?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that. You should use `Pattern#quote` since the JSON string might contain (in-)valid regex expressions, e.g. `{"display_name":"*"}` which would, when inserted, not match the literal `*` but would be a quantifier for the preceding `"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^<script>\n.*\n  box\('ns:.*','event', '%s', \{%s\}\);\n</script>$
```

Java:

```
String patternString = "^<script>\\n.*\\n  box\\('ns:.*','event', '%s', \\{%s\\}\\);\\n</script>$";
```

## Changes

1. Removed not needed or incorrectly placed parentheses
2. Added missing space after `'%s',`
3. Removed not needed quantifier `{1}`

---

It is not exactly clear from your question, but make sure you pass **two** objects to format since there are two format specifiers.

Make sure to [`quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) the values before inserting them into the pattern.

---

You can use tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for testing regex patterns, however it does not support Java regex notation and therefore some features might not be available or only in different form.

Comment: I tried the following in regex101: `^<script>\n.*\n  Krux\('ns:.*','admEvent', 'Mb-OWQYG', \{.*\}\);\n<\/script>$` and it matched the script. But, when I am trying to use this regex in my Java code, the regex final String regex = "^<script>\\n.*\\n  Krux\\('ns:.*','admEvent', 'Mb-OWQYG', \\{.*\\}\\);\\n<\\/script>$"; is always printing extra \'s. I don't know what I am doing wrong with escaping. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "The regex [...] is printing"? Also the backslashes in front of the parentheses have to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this regex java interprets it as:

```
(^<script>\n.*\n  box(\('ns:.*','event', '%s',)(\{%s\}){1}\)(;\n</script>$)
^... The opening parenthesis is without a corresponding closing parenthesis.
```

Thats why this regex gives you an error.